# Could this connection and query class be improved?

Tags: php, classes, pdo

Wrote this class it allows me to connect to database and display as many columns as I wish to. I can just give it desired parameters and I'm done. I've commented about the parameters that need it to be passed.

```
     include('connect.php');
   //include this file. This is our class

   $connection = new connection_to_db;
   //instantiate class

   $connection->make_connection("host_name", "user", "pass", "database_name");
   //1st param: your host name
   //2st param: your username
   //3rd param: your password
   //4th param: your database name

   $connection->run_test_query("shouts", "id", 2);
   //1st param: your table name.
   //2nd param: which column to show.
   //3rd param: how many results to display.

class connection_to_db{
     function make_connection($host, $user, $pass, $db){
       global $conn;
       try{
         $conn = new pdo("mysql: host=". $host . ";dbname=". $db, $user, $pass);         
       }catch(PDOException $error){
         echo $error->getMessage();
         die();
       }
     }

     function run_test_query($shouts, $column_to_show, $count){
       global $conn;
       $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $shouts LIMIT $count");
       $query->execute();

       while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
         echo $result["$column_to_show"] . "</br>";
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- convention for PHP class names is PascalCase, so your class should be `ConnectionToDb`.
- you are inconsistent with your indentation (2 vs 4 spaces).
- `select *` is discouraged. Don't just select everything if you only need one column, select only that column.
- [`limit` is actually a vector for SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886670/sql-injection-and-the-limit-clause). You should also [clean table before using it in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151413/how-to-protect-variable-table-names-against-sql-injection-in-php). Even if the data isn't user supplied right now, as this is a class, which is meant for reuse, you can never be sure how it will be used in the future.
- Don't just echo unsanitized data from the database (because it might be user supplied), this can result in an XSS vulnerability.
- [`</br>` isn't valid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br), use `<br>` or `<br />`
- I don't see the benefit of having this as a class. I would just remove `make_connection` and add the connection as a parameter to `run_test_query`.
- `run_test_query` isn't a very good name.